# taking string after a particularword in android

Tags: android

my problem is i have to add a search 
suggestion in my app.  It is Supposed to work like this:

if user writes "@"
 than the search box will show contacts.and if there is no contacts than it will store in the word after "@" shared preferences. if user presses "#" than it is supposed to show hash tags if it exists in my sq lite. and if not in db it will store itself in db.

```
subjectEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(#)");
        p .compile("(@)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(subjectEditText.getText().toString());
        while (m.find()){
            Toast.makeText(Addhash.this,"find",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use onkeypress listner and and chek the key press and if press @ then do what you want its the java way then right the furthor code it may solve your id

Answer (score 0):

Android has an AutoCompleteTextViewer (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) that takes in an adapter which you can use to do your parsing and searching in.

As for storing in the database, you should only do that when they finish typing so you should have an add button that will add it to those places.

Comment: i know that jsonof earth but i want if user touch #anyword it will store in db.  and if user enters @ it will open the autocompletetextview with contacts.

Comment: You could use this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#onKeyPreIme(int, android.view.KeyEvent). You check for the '#' and then set the autocomplete adapter to nothing and use (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)) to write out to your db. And if it's a '@' then you set the autocomplete to the contact list

Comment: would you please give me a code snippet for the #tag. to store in db. i created db already. you can give me the #tag in a string i will store it in my db. contact isnt most at this time. my boss need #tag works fine. pleaseeee

Comment: i just want to store the #word in my db. in a whole statement. like "taking #help from @jasonofearth. in this i have to store #help. in my db.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any db code so I don't know how you would store it in your db. Though given your description it looks like you can use your textwatcher above (though your trying to search for both things at the same time which seems problematic). Also how you'll get the contacts autocomplete I am not sure.

Comment: for a while please forget all. i have db. i just want to extract the word after #.  like i given example "i will have #tea after few minutes."  in this i need only tea in a string variable. please. in above code im trying to search both word. and tried for single word #. but if i writes #tea it finds # tag but keeps  continue loop. it not breaking.

Comment: That's because find will return true as long as some substring matches (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) try using (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#hitEnd()) to complete the loop