# getting values from sqlite using group by null pointer

Tags: sqlite

I have a table in that I have some duplicate record now I am getting the record without excluding duplicate records. I want to get all record excluding duplicate, and from duplicate data I want only one record. like if I have three same records i want only one record.
my query is like,this giving null pointer.

```
Cursor dCursor=database.rawQuery( "SELECT FROM note_image GROUP BY IDMATCHER",null,null);
```

and if I want to get this using query() method how can I do that. I am getting all records by using this method. but I want all records only once. without occurrence two time a record.

```
public Cursor fetchImage(){
    String[] columns = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.NOTE_IMG_ID,DatabaseHelper.NOTE_HD_IMG_PATH,DatabaseHelper.NOTE_IMG_PATH_THUMB,DatabaseHelper.TEMP_IMG_ID};
    Cursor cursor=database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NOTE_IMAGE,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    if (cursor!=null){
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT` http://www.geeksengine.com/database/basic-select/eliminate-duplicate-rows.php

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299334/android-adding-image-while-capturing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366843/filter-custom-adapter-with-four-arraylist-from-sqlite-in-listview-using-actionba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I done using this query. taken help from above commented link. ` public Cursor fetchImage() {
               Cursor icursor = database.query(true, DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NOTE_IMAGE, new String[]
                        {DatabaseHelper.TEMP_IMG_ID, DatabaseHelper.NOTE_IMG_PATH_THUMB},
                null, null, DatabaseHelper.TEMP_IMG_ID, null, null, null);
        if (icursor != null) {
            icursor.moveToNext();
        }
        return icursor;
    }`
```