# Filter Custom Adapter with four Arraylist from sqlite in listview using Actionbar SearchView

Tags: android

I have ListView and Custom Arrayadapter. I want to implement the action bar searchview to search in list items that are being fetched from Sqlite. If I search from list items it is showing only the first item (that item didn't search even) and the searched item disappears.

I tried this code but nothing happens. Here is my Search view's code. I want to search by titlelist.

```
 SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
         searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_view).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
       // searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
            {
                // this is your adapter that will be filtered
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                System.out.println("on text chnge text: "+newText);
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
            {
                // this is your adapter that will be filtered
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                System.out.println("on query submit: "+query);
                return true;
            }
        };
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);
```

and this is my custom Adapter's code.

```
public class CustomeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {    
public Context context;


public ArrayList<String> titleArrayList, descArrayList, timeArrayList, imgArrayList, IdArrayList;
List data;
int layoutResID;
private Bitmap myBitmap;


public CustomeAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<String> titleArrayList, ArrayList<String> descArrayList, ArrayList<String> timeArrayList, ArrayList<String> imgArrayList, ArrayList<String> IdArrayList) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, titleArrayList);
    this.context = context;
    this.titleArrayList = titleArrayList;
    this.descArrayList = descArrayList;
    this.timeArrayList = timeArrayList;
    this.imgArrayList = imgArrayList;
    this.IdArrayList = IdArrayList;

    this.data = data;
    this.layoutResID = layoutResourceId;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;


    final backAndFrontView sqView;


    if (rowView == null) {


        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
        sqView = new backAndFrontView();
        sqView.tag = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_fullnote);

        sqView.desc = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        sqView.time = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        sqView.id = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        sqView.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        sqView.button1 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button1);
        sqView.button2 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button2);
        sqView.button3 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button3);
        sqView.button4 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button4);
        rowView.setTag(sqView);
    } else {
        sqView = (backAndFrontView) rowView.getTag();
    }

    try {
        sqView.tag.setText(titleArrayList.get(position));
        sqView.desc.setText(descArrayList.get(position));
        sqView.time.setText(timeArrayList.get(position));
        sqView.id.setText(IdArrayList.get(position));
        sqView.id.setTag(IdArrayList.get(position).toString());
        if (imgArrayList.get(position).contains("null")) {
            sqView.img.setImageBitmap(null);
            sqView.img.setTag("null");
            sqView.img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            sqView.img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bounds.inSampleSize = 2;

            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgArrayList.get(position), bounds);
            //sqView.img.setImageBitmap((position & 1) == 1 ? myBitmap : myBitmap);
            String TAG = "tag";
            String id = String.valueOf(position);

            sqView.img.setTag(imgArrayList.get(position).toString());
            int width = myBitmap.getWidth();
            int height = myBitmap.getHeight();
            int newWidth = (height > width) ? width : height;
            int newHeight = (height > width) ? height - (height - width) : height;
            int crop = (width - height) / 2;
            crop = (crop < 0) ? 0 : crop;
            Bitmap cropImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap, crop, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            sqView.img.setImageBitmap(cropImg);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e.toString());
    }

    sqView.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Button 1 Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

    sqView.button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "Button 2 Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

    sqView.button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "Button 3 Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    sqView.button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "Button 4 Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return rowView;

}


protected static class backAndFrontView {
    protected TextView tag;
    protected TextView desc;
    protected TextView time;
    protected ImageView img;
    protected ImageView button1;
    protected ImageView button2;
    protected ImageView button3;
    protected ImageView button4;
    public TextView id;
}
```

}